# LiveData doesn't show data on configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have Search Fragment in which I make API call. It returns LiveData. Whenever I rotate phone, pop-up keyboard, I lose data, but my LiveData still has data(I checked by swithcing off Wi-Fi). I think I'm observing in wrong place. How can I solve this?
    **MusicSearchListFragment:**

```
class MusicSearchListFragment : ScopedFragment(), KodeinAware, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
override val kodein by closestKodein()
private val searchViewModelFactory: MusicSearchListViewModelFactory by instance()
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private lateinit var viewModel: MusicSearchListViewModel
private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private val resId = R.anim.layout_animation_waterfall
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment, container, false)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, searchViewModelFactory).get(MusicSearchListViewModel::class.java)
    progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_progressbar_search)
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_recycler_view) as? RecyclerView
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    return rootView
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()


    search_toolbar.apply {
        setIconifiedByDefault(false)
        requestFocus()
        setOnQueryTextListener(this@MusicSearchListFragment)
        isIconified = false
        requestFocusFromTouch()

    }
}

override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
    Log.d("myLog", "Make Retrofit Call")
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (query != null) {
            val searchedTracks = viewModel.searchTracks(query)
            searchedTracks.observe(this@MusicSearchListFragment, Observer {
                if (it == null) return@Observer
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                val adapter = MusicSearchListAdapter(
                    this@MusicSearchListFragment,
                    it.message.body.trackList
                )
                val animation: LayoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, resId)
                recyclerView!!.layoutAnimation = animation
                recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
            })
        } else Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
    return false
}
}
```

Comment: Make your searchedTracks a field in your view model this way it's state does not change on configuration change. Handle all your API calls inside the view model then in the Fragment in onViewCreated or onCreate (it doesn't really matter since the observer willl get called when the views are available) place an observer on your liveData, this way whenever the liveData chances and you your views are available they will be updated.

Comment: @Mihai Thank you I got it. How can I pass query string to viewModel. I am also using Kodein DI, maybe you got idea?

Comment: Well you pass it the same way you do now just call the function on the viewModel directly but instead of getting the the livedata back  you just update the field inside your viewModel when data comes back and that will call your observer and then your views will get updated. Also you should use "searchedTracks.observe( viewLifecycleOwner , Observer {}" when using fragments there is something to do with the lifeCycles of fragments .

Comment: Or you could store it with a `MutableLiveData` and use `Transformers.switchMap()` with it.

Comment: I had difficulty to implement with Transformations, because of suspend fun. However, I am getting NPE in below code, any idea guys? 
 **MusicSearchListViewModel:**   
        
       `private val querySearch = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun search(query: String = "") {
        querySearch.value = query
        Log.d("myLog", querySearch.value)
    }

    val searchedTracks by lazyDeferred {
        //Problem here
        tracksRepository.getSearchedTracksList(querySearch.value!!)
    }`